# Amazon DAX client throws "No endpoints available" exception

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-vpc, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I am trying to connect to DAX from a localhost using the following code:

```
    ClientConfig daxConfig = new ClientConfig()
            .withEndpoints("dax-cluster.yhdqu5.clustercfg.dax.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:8111");
    AmazonDaxClient client = new ClusterDaxClient(daxConfig);
```

The cluster is up and running, I've created it in a public subnet and opened port 8111 in the security group, but despite this I receive the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No endpoints available
    at com.amazon.dax.client.cluster.Cluster.leaderClient(Cluster.java:560)
    at com.amazon.dax.client.dynamodbv2.ClusterDaxClient$3.getClient(ClusterDaxClient.java:154)
    at com.amazon.dax.client.dynamodbv2.ClusterDaxClient$RetryHandler.makeRequestWithRetries(ClusterDaxClient.java:632)
    ... 10 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No endpoints available
        ... 13 more
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No endpoints available
            ... 13 more
```

Other answers on StackOverflow suggest that this may be caused by incorrectly configured security group and to test it I've launched an instance in the same VPC/subnet and used the same security group and I was able to ssh to this host (both 22nd and 8111-st ports are opened in the security group). So there should be some other DAX related reason.

The firewall on my machine is turned off.

But if I ssh to a machine in EC2, then I can connect to the DAX cluster:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-44 ~]$ nc -z dax-cluster.yhdqu5.clustercfg.dax.use1.cache.amazonaws.com 8111
Connection to dax-cluster.yhdqu5.clustercfg.dax.use1.cache.amazonaws.com 8111 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

Comment: You can only connect to DAX from an EC2 machine in the same VPC as the DAX cluster. Unless your localhost is an EC2 instance in the same VPC, it won't be able to connect to the DAX cluster.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only connect to DAX from an EC2 machine in the same VPC as the DAX cluster. Unless your localhost is an EC2 instance in the same VPC, it won't be able to connect to the DAX cluster.

Comment: Can someone explain why this is the case? Why would they have this restriction? Is there anyway around it? I have a service that lives in another cloud provider that I want to access DAX.

Comment: you can use VPN Connections to connect dev machine or server in another cloud provider to "appear" in the same VPC as the Dax cluster

Comment: Ah the hours I wasted on this. I thought it's a security group issue. Then I scp my program binary to EC2, run it, and voila... I queried an Item from my DAX. Indeed. VPN or EC2.

Answer (score 5):

If you are making call from your lambda, make sure you have the lambda running with in the same vpc, it has granted iam role to access dax and it has opened the dax port for the security group

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to access it from outside the VPC, You will have to create a [NLB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/introduction.html) which fronts the dax replicas. Then you need to use [VPC endpoint service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/endpoint-service.html) to provide a link which can access this. You can then use the endpoints provided to make calls.

```
VPCEndpoint -> NLB -> Dax replica 1
                   -> Dax replica 2
```

You can then used code sample below to connect to DAX

```
import com.amazon.dax.client.dynamodbv2.DaxClient;
AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDb = new DaxClient(
                "vpce-XXX-YYY.vpce-svc-ZZZ.us-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com",
                8111, region, credentials);
```

Comment: How do you point a NLB to a DAX cluster? None of the target group options seem to be able to, since the DAX cluster doesn't have EC2 instance, visible IP addresses, or a load balancer you can select.