# How to invoke a Lambda function locally from a VPC (Serverless)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, amazon-vpc

I am using the serverless framework which lets you invoke Lambda functions locally.

I have now made a Dax cluster which requires a VPC and granting permissions to the security group to use the service.  I have a Lambda function configured to use the VPC and that works great now.

But when I try to invoke locally it does not work:

```
amazondax.DaxError.DaxClientError: An error occurred (NoRouteException) when calling the  operation: Failed to configure cluster endpoints from {daxarn}
```

I am assuming it's because my local invocation is not done from the VPC.  If I am right, is there a way to do this?

Thank you very much in advance for any pointers or any help at all!

Comment: This might be the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46026610/amazon-dax-client-throws-no-endpoints-available-exception/62094056#62094056

Comment: I'm considering making a clause for local where it just uses Dynamo

Comment: Setting up a vpn connection you could access yr vpc locally

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  Ideally the solution would allow more than one dev to use the setup without each having to have much extra to install.  The annoyance of the alternative (using a NLB) is that there is already an API in front of this and I just want to make test queries occasionally.  An NLB seems like a slegehammer for a nut.